# GCC: Questions regarding GCC 'optimisation' and 'inline' definition

Tags: optimization, gcc, inline

My questions are the following:

1) If I tell GCC **not to** optimise the code existing into a specific source file, then this will be applied to all the functions called from this file (which may reside into different source files) or only to the functions/code that exist locally in this file? That is, will the file optimisation have recursive behaviour or not?

2) If I declare a function as inline (so that I don't get the function overhead) and this function is declared into a file in which I force GCC to apply no optimisation, then if I call the function from **another** source file, will I still get the no optimisation effect?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To question number 2:

If you include a header vile with a inline function in another source, then the function will be inlined, it does not make sense to compile it before it has been inlined.

Answer (score 0):

Optimisation is not recursive - if you don't optimise a file, then its only the functions in that file which will not be optimised. As for inline, the function may be inlined in the file into which it is compiled, normally via the #include mechanism, if that is what you are asking (which is far from clear).